# How to make a view height grow depending on its child views contents

Tags: ios, autolayout, uistoryboard, nslayoutconstraint, ios-autolayout

I have a parent view whose height has to be decided by its child content.

How may I achieve this in storyboard without programatically changing it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can accomplish this using AutoLayout.

Make sure each of the child views has constraints defining its size and position. Then, set the parent view's vertical content hugging and compression resistance priorities to required. This will define the parent's height based on the height and positioning of its child views.

Note that depending on what the child views are, you may want to change their vertical content hugging and compression resistance priorities as well. For example, a UILabel with `numberOfLines` set to `0` can automatically grow based on its content, so you'd want it to hug its content vertically and resist vertical compression so that it resizes the parent view.

This image shows the parent (white) view with its vertical hugging and compression resistance priorities set in the inspector panel. Notice that the parent view has constraints set for its width, x-position, and y-position, but not its height. It's able to infer its height based on the height and position of the child views (see the next image).

[image]

This image shows the constraints of each child view. Notice that the vertical hugging and compression resistance priorities of these views were **not** changed. Each of these views has constraints for x-position and y-position, but you'll notice that not all of them have constraints for width and height. Views like the label and switch are able to automatically infer their size constraints based on their content. If you don't set vertical position constraints on every one of the child views, AutoLayout won't know how much space each of them needs, so it won't know how tall the parent view should be.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for explaining.I couldn't understand can you explain how to do this with image or series of instruction for below scenario .. I have a view(Parent) and it has one switch and two labels and one button vertically one after another.

Comment: if you could explain me more about resistance and hugging that would be good too

Comment: Hi @Ranjithkumar — I've edited my answer with sample screenshots and explanations.

Comment: @JohnWickham content Hugging/Compression is not for that.

Comment: @alegelos do you have official documentation supporting that? When I tested, layouts in which other constraints with higher priority act on the "container" view would prevent that view's content from determining its height.

Comment: @JohnWickham - Can you please explain me the compression and hugging ? I couldn;t get this concept ... your help will be appreciated very much

Comment: @Ranjithkumar theres a link about compression hugging.

Answer (score 1):

1- Add you View container and add constraints. Don't set height nor bottom spacing or set it but with less priority (example 999).

2- Add items/things to your View Container and add constraints. Be sure to add all require constraints plus add bottom spacing to the bottom item inside.

That will define the height of the container View.

[image]

[image]

PD: Forget about [Content Hugging/Compression and Priority](https://krakendev.io/blog/autolayout-magic-like-harry-potter-but-real). They are handy but no use here. They just set a resistance to get bigger or smaller.